# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory (Python 3.10)

Tags: python

I am defining the path to the file and joining the path. When I run the test it is adding the double backslashes to the path and throwing the error "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory"

example:

Test.py

```
test_file_path = 'C:\folder1\folder2\folder3'
test_file_name = test_file_path + "Resultfile" + '_Test.xlsx'
```

======

```
test_result_file = Test.test_file_name
print("test_result_file")
```

when executing this I am receiving an error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: "C:\\Folder1\\Folder2\\Folder3\\Resultfile_Test.xlsx"
```

Comment: Hi, can you confirm file path exists in the given location? `C:\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\Resultfile_Test.xlsx`

Comment: Hello, yes I checked it couple of times and made sure the path and the file exists

Comment: I have added answer with some code, as I was not able to add formatted code in the comment. Can you test and share the output?

Comment: Thanks for sharing it, however its still throwing the same error.

Comment: I have added different conditions, can you share what was printed on terminal

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and [mre], and do not add irrelevant tags to the question (this clearly has nothing to do with Selenium).

Answer (score -1):

Can you try os.path for building file location and share the output? In comments, I wasn't able to add formatted code.

```
from os import path

class Test:
    test_file_name = None
    test_file_path = path.join("C:\\", "folder1", "folder2", "folder3")
    if path.exists(test_file_path):
        test_file_name = path.join(test_file_path, "Resultfile" + '_Test.xlsx')
        if path.exists(test_file_name):
            print(f"File exists, path: {test_file_name}")
        else:
            print(f"File does not exist, path: {test_file_name}")
    else:
        print(f"Folder does not exist, path: {test_file_path}")


test_result_file = Test.test_file_name
print(test_result_file)
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not simply do this?

```
import os.path

# stores whether given file exists or not
result = os.path.isfile(r'C:\folder1\folder2\folder3\Resultfile_Test.xlsx')
print(result)
```